# .NET core docker - how to find the entry app after dotnet publish

Tags: docker, .net-core

Following all .NET Core guides basically boils down to a `dotnet publish` and copying the output of that to `/app`, then running `dotnet myapp.dll`.

I have about 40+ (and growing) products running in this setup, and so modifying all dockerfiles with `myapp.dll` gets quite laborious.

I was wondering if there is some way to find out what the entry dll is during publish? (e.g. with `--self-contained` the cli generates an arch specific entry file, so you can use that name, but it seems like an unnecessary step given that publish takes longer)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a bash script which will extract project name, and next create a valid path with replacing it in script file.

If you are in solution folder just run: (bash)

```
PROJECT_NAME=`find ./ -name "*.sln" | head -n 1 | cut -d '/' -f 2 | sed 's/.sln//'`
```

If you have solution file **myapp.sln** , this command will return value **myapp**

Then you pass this value to script:

```
./runScript.sh "$PROJECT_NAME"
```

And inside this script:

```
dotnet "/app/$1.dll"
```

For dockerfiles you have replace all occurences of eg. **{{PROJECT_NAME}}** in file to value of variable. Now i don't remember command, but **sed** is useful for that.

Comment: The .sln file is not published into my /app folder? I want to run the command AFTER publish,inside docker